# Angular proxy config; proxying URL get parameters

Tags: angular, proxy

I need to add a proxy config to make GET requests to a webservice running on another domain (I'm testing on localhost:4200). I've added the following `proxy.conf.json` file to the root of the project

```
{
  "/address/*": {
    "target": "https://api-url.com/address/",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

and added the `--proxy-config=proxy.conf.json` flag to the `ng serve` command in `package.json`. My GET request is pretty simple;

```
const url = `/address/cities?cityName=&zipCode=2000&languageCode=NL`;

const result = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET'
});

return await result.json();
```

I can see the proxy works as `[HPM] GET /address/cities?cityName=&zipCode=2000&languageCode=NL -> https://api-url.com/address/` gets logged to the terminal, but the actual request doesn't work as nothing after `/address/` is proxied. Is it at all possible to pass the URL params to the proxy?

Comment: What’s logged the console by the development proxy doesn’t show the full proxied URL. What are you seeing in the network tab? Do you get the response you expect?

Comment: Network tab shows the request URL as `http://localhost:4200/address/cities?cityName=&zipCode=2000&languageCode=NL`, but I get `Internal server error` as a response. If I try the request in my browser directly and replace `localhost:4200` with the actual API url, the request works fine. `Internal server error` is the reply you get when required parameters are missing, so I assume that's the problem.

Comment: For troubleshooting, I created a simple server with route handler for `GET /address/cities` and using your exact proxy configuration I got the same proxy console output, but I was successfully able to pass query parameters `cityName`, `zipCode`, and `languageCode` using the exact URL you are using in your GET request. Your proxy configuration is correct. You will need to debug the response from the server, for example in your URL `cityName` doesn't have a value, could that cause a 500 error from the API? Does this API support CORS? It's hard to help without knowing the exact error happening.

Comment: Like I said, if I open the URL in the browser (so not through a fetch request in Angular) and replace `localhost:4200` with the API url it works just fine, even with an empty `cityName` value. I don't know enough about their API to really answer anything else, so I think I'll have to find another way of solving the issue. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Just to get back to this, turns out I had to remove the `/address` part from the target. So instead of `"target": "https://api-url.com/address/",` it has to be `"target": "https://api-url.com/"`.

Comment: You should post it as an answer to help others. Is the API/server that’s on the external domain going to be hosting the built static assets of this angular application? Or is the angular application going to be hosted separately from the API? I ask because if they are/will be separated, you don’t need a proxy, you can use target the full separate url in the HTTP requests.

Answer (score 4):

As was posted in one of the comments the answer is to remove `/address` from the target.

```
{
  "/address/*": {
    "target": "https://api-url.com/",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

We also had an issue with the URL parameters not being proxied correctly if the `/`was missing at the end of the target.